# Unable to cast object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using this : http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

In a column I have multiple textboxes binded to some columns from database. 
My goal is to get the value from those textboxes that are maskedit.
Since there are 4 controls in the column I'm trying to get the values like this:

```
String firstTXT = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[1])).Text;
String SecondTXT = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[5].Controls[2])).Text;
```

I can get the value from the firsttexbox without any error ( but it's also masked ) .
and when I Try to get from the second I get : 
`Unable to cast object of type 'AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'`.

Is there any chance to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the third control in the cell is the `MaskedEditExtender` that augments your first text box. Depending on your markup, you might want to get the fourth control instead:

```
string secondTXT = ((TextBox) row.Cells[5].Controls[3]).Text;
```

Or, better, give `id` attributes to your text boxes and use [FindControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to get them:

```
string firstTXT = ((TextBox) row.Cells[5].FindControl("firstID")).Text;
string secondTXT = ((TextBox) row.Cells[5].FindControl("secondID")).Text;
```